# Кто прошёл аудит?

Tags: предложение, локализация, аудит

В очереди проверок система иногда подсовывает фиктивные задания для проверки внимательности участника. По результатам такой проверки выносится вердикт:

- > Проверка прошла аудит $when$:
- > Проверка не прошла аудит $when$:

Оригинальный текст выглядит следующим образом:

- > Review audit passed $when$:
- > Review audit failed $when$:

Считаю, что существующая версия перевода не совсем грамотная и предлагаю её пересмотреть.

Comment: "Зачёт"/"Незачёт". ))

Comment: **"ок"** / **"не"**

Comment: [**1**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4972/%d0%9a%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%91%d0%bb-%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82#comment18154_4972) / [**0**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4972/%d0%9a%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%91%d0%bb-%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82#comment18154_4972)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ещё один вариант - можно упростить термин **"аудиторская проверка"** до **"аудит"**:

- > Аудит пройден $when$:
- > Аудит провален $when$:

---

Вариант утверждён на Transifex. Будет доступен, скорее всего, 27.03.2017.

Comment: Лаконично. Но несколько смущает "провален". В официальных документах так пишут?

Comment: В официальных документах результатом аудита является "аудиторское заключение" =) Там всё не так однобитово.

Comment: какой-то бинарный вердикт вполне может быть. Например, в виде печати на титульном листе акта :)

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. аудит (проверку) проходит участник, то так и должно быть сказано в тексте:

- > Участник прошёл аудит $when$:
- > Участник не прошёл аудит $when$:

Answer (score -1):

Считаю, что **"review audit"** должно переводиться, как **"Аудит проверки"**.
Хоть это и пахнет тавтологией, оригинальный смысл именно такой.

Вариант перевода:

- > Аудит проверки пройден $when$:
- > Аудит проверки провален $when$:

Comment: Разные варианты хорошо бы оформить разными ответами. Иначе не понятно как голосовать.

Comment: 3 ответа? Мне не трудно)

Comment: Угу. Разбиение прошло успешно :)

Answer (score -1):

Можно забыть то, что аудит касается очереди ревью, и переводить **"audit review"**, как единое целое: **"аудиторская проверка"**.

- > Аудиторская проверка пройдена $when$:
- > Аудиторская проверка провалена $when$: